# Does the Windows 8 SDK support SQL Server Compact Edition?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embedded database for windows 8 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655186/embedded-database-for-windows-8-app)

My current apps for Windows 7 use the entity framework code with SQL Server Compact Edition. Is this technology supported by the Windows 8 SDK? How can we develop database-based Windows 8 apps?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876 , System Requirements

Comment: Why can't Microsoft make it to support Windows 8.

Comment: IMHO, I don't think you need EF with a SQL CE when building Metro Apps. SQLite is enough because if you would build a enterprise app for Metro I think they want you to push to Azure. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

No it does not.  Furthermore, ADO.NET is not part of the .NET Core profile available to Metro style applications.  Remote storage via web services is obviously one potential model, but if you absolutely need a local DB, here is a [good series](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx) from Tim Heuer on how to use SQLite with Windows 8 Metro style apps.

Answer (score 0):

Kelvin remember that Metro isn't only for PC. It's also targeted for tablets (mobile devices) where every second of work of the CPU is a battery cost. Better app = less battery cos. Mobile apps should be lite, fast and do less than more when they don't need to do something :)
Thats why only SQLite is supported, that is why you can't use heavy and complex database server.
If you want to use a compled DB JP is says the truth. You need to use Azure. I'm doing this in my app and it works just fine. You app will work smoother cause all DB operation are done on Azure and this is good for your application.

But the most important thing. You need to remember that metro app = normal PC but ALSO tablets and maybe phones. If you want to create a complex desktop app like on Win7 make it a normal desktop app don`t try to push it to metro. Not every desktop app is a good material for metro app

Comment: SQL Server Compact Edition should be ligth weight too.